# How to quickly switch between designer and source code mode in QtCreator?

Tags: windows, qt-creator

Is there a functionality like `View Code` in Microsoft Visual Studio where we can instantly go to the source code relating to the control/or form we are coding?

At the moment there is only an Edit button on the left upper corner of QtCreator which when clicked shows some xml related codes (design related I guess).

I have to double click on the source code I need to work on. Is there a way or plugin to directly navigate to the active source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Ctrl-F4 also has the same effect :)

Comment: I don't think Ctrl+F4 is universal. For me it's a system shortcut.